# How to clear errors object in vee-validate?

Tags: vue.js

I'd like to clear all the errors from vee-validate in a sign out method, following code seems not working, the errors in the form is still being shown, why?

```
sign_out: function (e) {
    console.log('sign me out')
    var self = this
    firebase.auth().signOut().then(function () {

      console.log('sign out!')         
      self.info.email = ''
      self.errors.clear()  // clear errors object of vee-validate

    }, function (error) {

      console.log('sign out failed')

    })
  },
```

here is a jsFiddle that describe the problem in code, when you type '123', a warning is shown, then when you click 'clear', the field is set to '', and errors.clear(), was expecting the warning in the form will go away, but it is not:

https://jsfiddle.net/8j3z82bv/1/

Comment: try to reset the dom value to empty string as you did with the email value.

Comment: how to reset dom value? actually v-model="info.email", I set it to "", then errors.clear(), but still shown 'email is required' in the form

Comment: Yeh i got the idea. try  `self.errors = {}`

Comment: thanks, tried, but not working

Comment: Try to modify your question and add your html code it will help the community to figure out what's wrong with your code.

Comment: added a jsfiddle, thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I have come up with another solution that could help. in your input we'll add another **listener** so it will be like this:

```
<input type="email" name="email" v-model="info.email" v-validate="'required|email'" @input="validate">
```

then will add the validate function that call vee-validate function so your vue instance will be something like this:

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        info: { email: '' }
    },

    methods: {

        onSignin: function (e) { },
        clear_proc: function (e) {
            delete this.info.email

            this.errors.clear()
        },
        validate: function () {
          this.$validator.validateAll();
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: i think  this.errors.clear() works, but since the rule is 'require|email', there will be an error generated after the clear(), is there a way to skip that error? in many case you like to empty all the fields in the form without an error warning until keyboard got pressed

Comment: Yes i got if that the case i would recommend you to create your own validation functionality since your form is no so big. but i think `delete` operator will do the trick isn't it?

Comment: delete works, I think custom validation is the way, looking at example, it has this new JS style, that looks confusing to me:

Comment: Yeah it's a little confusing at the beginning.

Comment: trying to validate in code instead of v-validate, following code returns a promise, then how to proceed:       var validator = this.$validator

          validator.attach('email', 'required|email'); // attach field.

          var rslt = validator.validateAll({ email: self.info.email, pwd: self.info.pwd })

Comment: delete this.info.email; this.errors.clear() should work, dont know why we need validate.  it turned out, it's more confusing to mix vv-validate with code for the original question, so I remove all vv-validate, and just verify in code, thanks

Answer (score 17):

Version (3.x)

`this.$refs.observer.reset();`

Comment: This work, but don't forget to add `ref='observer'` to your `<validation-observer>` tag, otherwise it will throw `Cannot read properties of undefined`

Comment: Worked great, for typescript use:
`(this.$refs.observer as ProviderInstance).reset();`

Answer (score 13):

If using vee-validate (2.x) use $validator as other answers clearly show:

```
this.$validator.reset();
```

However if using latest vee-validate (3.x), the **$validator** object is [no longer available](https://logaretm.github.io/vee-validate/migration.html#removed-injected-validator-property) and you can add a ref to the *ValidationObserver*:

```
<validation-observer v-slot="{ invalid }" ref="form">
  <v-form @submit.prevent="save">
    ...
    <v-btn @click.stop="reset">Reset</v-btn>
    <v-btn type="submit" :disabled="invalid">Save</v-btn>
  </v-form>
</validation-observer>
```

and then you can either invoke a reset in code as documented [here](https://logaretm.github.io/vee-validate/guide/forms.html#programmatic-access-with-refs):

```
reset() {
  this.$refs.form.reset();
  ...
}
```

or you could expose the built in **reset** function on the **v-slot** as documented [here](https://logaretm.github.io/vee-validate/guide/forms.html#resetting-forms):

```
<validation-observer v-slot="{ invalid, reset }" ref="form">
  <v-form @submit.prevent="save" @reset.prevent="reset">
    ...
    <v-btn type="reset">Reset</v-btn>
    <v-btn type="submit" :disabled="invalid">Save</v-btn>
  </v-form>
</validation-observer>
```

Answer (score 12):

This worked for me:

```
this.form.name = '';
this.form.email = '';

this.$nextTick(() => {
    this.errors.clear();
    this.$nextTick(() => {
        this.$validator.reset();
    });
});
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, the "$nextTick" clousure does the trick! also remember you can use this.errors.clear('scope') to clear only certain fields or forms

Answer (score 7):

Use following method:

`this.errors.clear()`

Answer (score 4):

Use the following:

```
this.$validator.clean();
```

Comment: what if i want to get the all error message how can i get them after validation on the JavaScript side.

Comment: That's deprecated, but the replacement works:
vee-validate.js: [vee-validate] validator.clean is marked for deprecation, please use validator.reset instead.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I wanted to clear errors and then, validate. This worked for me:

```
this.$validator.reset().then(resolve => {
        this.$validator.validateAll().then((isValid) => {
            if (isValid) {
                ...
            }
       })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

use this.$refs.form.reset() it works for me in vue 2.6+

Answer (score 0):

With vee-validate (4.x), for an email validation,

```
const { value, resetField } = useField<string>('email', yup.string().email());

const resetButtonAction = () => {
    resetField();
}
```

Navigate to the [docs](https://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v4/api/use-field) for further reference.